# How can I solve error C2059: syntax error : 'string'"

Tags: c++, class, syntax, compiler-errors

Here is my code:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(const char*);
};

class Bar
{
  public:
    Foo bu("adfds");
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}

Foo::Foo(const char* iLoc)
{ }
```

When I try to create a `Foo` class within the `Bar` class, I get the syntax error when trying to pass to the constructor.  Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer this to egrunin's answer as you don't have to track memory allocation.

```
class Bar
{

private:

    Foo bu;

public:

    Bar()
    : bu("adfds")
    {
    }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't initialize `bu` in the class declaration. Is this what you want?

```
class Bar
{
public:
    Foo *bu;

    Bar() {
        bu = new Foo("adfds");
    }
};
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, here's a way of doing it without making `bu` a pointer:

```
class Bar : bu("adfds")
{
public:
    Foo bu;
};
```

Comment: Surely `Bar() : bu("adfds") {}` would have sufficed?

Comment: I think I understand.. so I have to initialize bu in the Bar class constructor?

Comment: I'm so confused.. so I have to do this anytime I want to use a class in another class?

Comment: @todda.speot.is: I figured the more verbose example would be clearer to a beginner. I've appended your suggestion.

Comment: You've misunderstood my suggestion. I'm initializing bu in the constructor, to save the effort of dynamically allocating memory. Not deriving from bu.

Comment: @todda.speot.is: oh boy, need more coffee. Yes, and it's good you put it in a separate answer so I can upvote it :)